# ImageView in SurfaceView without XML

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, surfaceview

My question is if is possible add an ImageView in a SurfaceView without XML.  If yes, how? I have a main class that has the function of GamePanel, and for apply a Method i need to call it with an ImageView, but i don't know if it is possible. Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read about the View and ViewGroups provided by the Android Framework.

I am giving the quick understanding to propose the solution.

**Crash Course about View & ViewGroup**

At the root of the Android UI system, everything is `View`.

**What is a `View`?**
    It is a single widget / UI component that can be displayed on the screen. The View includes Buttons, TextViews, **ImageViews**, **SurfaceView**. They can not contain any child view i.e. They can not hold declaration for the any other child view

Following XML definition is ***incorrect***: *A view can not hold another view*

```
<SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/textSurfaceView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</SurfaceView>
```

**What is `ViewGroup`?**

Inherited from View and designed to contain and arrange more than one `View` also called as Child views. The various `ViewGroups` are LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout etc.

Following XML definition is ***Correct***: *A ViewGroup can hold another view*

```
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">   
    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Here comes the solution**
Step-1: Add a ViewGroup in your XML wrapping the existing SurfaceView. As mentioned already the ViewGroups are LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout etc.

*res/layouts/your_layout.xml*

```
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/baseFrame"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">   
    <SurfaceView 
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Step-2: At the time of view creation add an ImageView to the FrameLayout. `onCreate()` activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
FrameLayout baseFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.baseFrame);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setWidth(/*As per your need*/);
imageView.setHeight(/*As per your need*/);
imageView.setId(/*Any unique positive Number*/ R.ids.imageView1); <= Required to access this view later
/*Set the layout parameters such as layout_gravity as well.*/
baseFrame.addView(imageView);
```

Step-3: I know you must be wondering about the ImageView Id. I am giving the quicker way to assign an ID to a View.

- Create a file ids.xml at res/values
- Fill the following details.

  ```
  <resources>
      <item type="id" name="imageView1" />
  </resources>
  ```

Step-4: Passing an ImageView to the method

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
methodToBeCalled(myImageView);
```

I hope that helps.
Happy Coding!!!